Directus all API endpoints are returning 404 error
I have uploaded my directus code into the ssh server.
But none of my APIs endpoint whether POST or GET is working, all returning 404 errors.
However I can see all content, all items, can login etc.
I am running my frontend in: http://platform.groep-e.be:8080/
And my backend is running on: http://platform.groep-e.be:8055/
Followed this article: https://docs.directus.io/blog/deploy-directus-ubuntu-server.html
Am I missing something over association of APIs endpoint in backend?
In the localhost the project is working totally fine, all endpoints working. I don't know what's either missing or wrong that all API endpoints are responding: route not found.
One of the GET request for testing: curl http://platform.groep-e.be:8055/akeneoproducts
How to make all endpoints of Directus to respond and work.
